# Сбор данных по светофорам

Tags: яндекс-карты

Я работаю над дипломным проектом по дорожной инфраструктуре. Мне необходимо собрать данные по количеству светофоров в городах России. В Яндекс.картах  имеются обозначения всех перекрестков и всех светофорных объектов. Возможно ли как-то получить из API данные по типу: город; количество светофоров на карте? Или город и название всех перекрестков со светофорами? Спасибо.

Comment: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/NlK

Comment: Выгрузить такие данные из Яндекс.Карт нельзя, разве что вы направите им запрос и они поделятся статистикой

Comment: Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать куда конкретно  нужно обратиться с таким вопросом в Яндексе?