# Как найти географические координаты всех мостов в России?

Tags: python, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api, карты

Хочу получить координаты всех мостов через реки России, как это можно сделать быстрее всего?

Comment: Kакой язык программирования?

Comment: тут недавно был [вопрос про все светофоры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1037405/223826), возможно там найдете ответ.

Comment: угу, там ссылка на построитель запросов по osm, отличная штука, рекомендую

Answer (score 2):

Смотря какая у Вас задача. Точные плановые координаты Вы точно нигде не получите - эту информацию можно получить только с топокарт. Но если это и не требуется, можно воспользоваться OSM. Однако мосты там часто не выделены как отдельный объект (пример: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/56.97234/39.27148). Думаю оптимальный путь тогда примерно такой:

1. Загрузить слой дорог РФ из OSM
2. Загрузить слой рек РФ из OSM
3. Каждое пересечение объектов в этих слоях как раз и есть мост.

Очень легко все это сделать в какой-нибудь ГИС (QGIS как бесплатный вариант). Там можно и выгрузить данные с охватом РФ и посчитать пересечение.

P.S. Конечно, в крупных городах есть и тоннели под реками, но их количество крайне невелико.

Answer (score 0):

Можно выгрузить из OSM.
Не знаю как прям все все, это нигде не получить, только организовывать свою геодезическую съёмку и сбор данных. 
Но из OSM можно получить большинство мостов.